# why is the pipenv install of spyder causing a complete python tree install?

Tags: python-3.x, spyder, pipenv

## Just installing spyder3 in a pipenv

reports it finds the **spyder requirement** (and 2 others) **already satisfied**. However, **pipenv continues** with the installation of **~600 MB** of python packages in the virtual environment.

To work with spyder3 and the latest ipywidgets on **ubuntu disco**, I set up a

```
pipenv --three --site-packages.
```

I am working on scipy simulation code and want to have simple widgets for some needed config functionality, so I thought: "why not do use widgets in a jupyter notebook?"

The *ipywidgets distro package* release (6.0.*) is *quite behind* the latest version (7.5.*), so some things were uglier or unimplemented.

So before further steps, I want to set up spyder within the created pipenv. It is already installed an the system, so there shouldn't be happening too much:

```
pipenv install spyder
```

But this results in a longer waiting period and the install of 83 packages,

▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉ 83/83 — 00:00:50

For getting what I already had.

- python 3.7.3
- spyder 3.3.2

I'd like to **understand why** the install is getting so big, since this is the kind of behavior I'd rather avoid (i.e. by not using anaconda).

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) You should avoid using pip and pipenv if you're using Python for scientific computing (you'll save yourself a lot of headaches, believe me). Also, if you want to avoid the big Anaconda installation, please download Miniconda instead and use conda to install what you need.

Comment: thanks @CarlosCordoba
I thought pipenv was the recommended way to go, regarding virtual environments...
but as it seems, *conda has established itself as the de-facto standard

Comment: Pipenv has lot of issues, it's not well maintained and IMHO it's an immature project that got promoted before time. So you should be much better using conda (which is what most maintainers of the Python scientific ecosystem use and recommend).